# Header logo disappears when the dimension changes on Wordpress Visible up to 979width?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

https://impacrealty.co/

Also, I updated the NameServer settings & the layout of my Wordpress has been changed, Featured articles links are not working?

Any idea? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this line present in your `wp-content/themes/revolution_city_gray-10-back/css/responsive.css`

`@media (max-width: 979px)`

Create a child theme and copy the `responsive.css` and remove that line from the code.

Hope this helps.